# Pasar datos a un modal

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una lista de clientes desplegados en una tabla utilizando un bucle forelse. Dentro de esta lista, muestro en un modal información de cada uno de los clientes de la lista en especifico. Para esto pongo el include del modal dentro del bucle y le paso la variable que quiero mostrar.

Lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
                @forelse ($clientes as $cliente) 

                <td>{{ $cliente->nombre_cliente }}</td>

                <td>{{ $cliente->num_documento }}</td>

                <td>{{ $cliente->clave_oficina_virtual }}</td>

                <td>{{ $cliente->clave_tss }}</td>

                <td>{{ $cliente->cedula_tss }}</td>

                <td>{{ $cliente->clave_sirla }}</td>
                
                <td>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="link-primary" data-target="#show_tarjeta_clave" >
                        <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                    </a>

                    @include('clientes.modals.show_tarjeta_clave', ['documento' => $cliente->num_documento])
                </td>
                
            </tr>
            
            @empty

                <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h5><i class="icon fas fa-info"></i> No hay datos</h5>
                    No se encontraron clientes para mostrar.
                </div>

            @endforelse
```

Y en el modal esta de esta forma:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="show_tarjeta_clave" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content ">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Detalles cliente</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    
  <div class="modal-body">

    {{ $documento }}
  </div>
    
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

El problema aqui es que sin importar que hago el include del modal dentro del foreach la información que muestra en todos los modals de cualquier cliente es del primer cliente de la lista. Es como si no se actualizara la variable que le paso al include en cada racionero.

Comment: primero que todo no es recomendable que renderices todos esos modales ya que es una componente que puedes reusar solo cambiando la data, segundo solo se ve el primero porque no tienes un id dinámico, tienes dos opciones, o mandas un id y target dinamico o pasada la data por js, dependiendo que cual opcion quieras te puedo ayudar

Comment: @NicolasAldana gracias por responder. Como puedo enviar un id y target dinámico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para el caso que mencionas que quieres un modal con id dinámico debes asignar el id en el loop así, aunque no es la manera mas optima y mas limpia te va servir

```
 @forelse ($clientes as $cliente) 

                <td>{{ $cliente->nombre_cliente }}</td>

                <td>{{ $cliente->num_documento }}</td>

                <td>{{ $cliente->clave_oficina_virtual }}</td>

                <td>{{ $cliente->clave_tss }}</td>

                <td>{{ $cliente->cedula_tss }}</td>

                <td>{{ $cliente->clave_sirla }}</td>
                
                <td>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="link-primary" data-target="#show_tarjeta_clave-{{$cliente->num_documento}}" >
                        <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                    </a>

                    @include('clientes.modals.show_tarjeta_clave', ['documento' => $cliente->num_documento])
                </td>
                
            </tr>
            
            @empty

                <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h5><i class="icon fas fa-info"></i> No hay datos</h5>
                    No se encontraron clientes para mostrar.
                </div>

            @endforelse
```

y en tu modal colocas la data del id igual

```
<div class="modal fade" id="show_tarjeta_clave-{{$documento}}" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content ">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Detalles cliente</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    
  <div class="modal-body">

    {{ $documento }}
  </div>
    
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo.